Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵcmp')
Don't know why [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵcmp')] this error continues..
need help
i'm making Angular standalone based local library, with also standalone based local project
@Component({
  selector: 'lib-attr-left-menu-bar',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RobotInfoBarManagerViewComponent,
    RobotMissionListViewComponent
  ],
  template: `
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li (click)="clickMenu(menu)" *ngFor="let menu of menus.slice(0, menus.length - 1);" [class]="menu.class" [class.active]="menu.active">
          <i></i>
          <p>{{ menu.name }}</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li (click)="clickMenu(menus[menus.length - 1])" [class]="menus[menus.length - 1].class"  [class.active]="menus[menus.length - 1].active">
          <i></i>
          <p>{{ menus[menus.length - 1].name }}</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <lib-robot-info-bar-manager-view *ngIf="selectedMenu !== undefined" [divHideOption]="(selectedMenu.class == 'main-nav_1' && selectedMenu.active)"></lib-robot-info-bar-manager-view>
    <lib-robot-mission-list-view *ngIf="selectedMenu !== undefined" [divHideOption]="(selectedMenu.class == 'main-nav_2' && selectedMenu.active)"></lib-robot-mission-list-view>
  `,
  styleUrl: './attr-left-menu-bar.component.css'
})


after i trigger clickMenu function, selector of child's component doesnt work and keep making errors  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵcmp').
i already export those three components from my local library's public-api.ts

Does this answer your question? TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵcmp') Angular
